# Change url in codeigniter through routes and url library

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
http:/site_name/fanpage/profile/[string]/[num]/listensong/audio/[encoded id]
```

I want to change it to:

```
http:/site_name/[string]/[num]/listensong/audio/[encoded id]
```

through routes in codeigniter. This url is generated via the url library in CodeIgniter, which I want to change.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html has the information you need for achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using the routing library:](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

```
// add to application/config/routes.php
$route['products/(\w+)/(\d+)/listensong/audio/(\w+)'] = "fanpage/profile/$1/$2/listensong/audio/$3";
```

Comment: Thank you so much cwallen it really works.what i have to write if i want to do exactly opposite of it means changing the second url to the first one